# Directory deny in PHP?

Tags: php, security

How can i deny users except admin on a spesific folder using PHP?

Comment: apache is more suitable for that

Comment: What kinds of users? Web users?

Comment: apache is more suitable but how?

Comment: @Pekka: i want to deny users who is not admin.

Comment: @pegasus you need to add more detail. How is it determined who is admin?

Comment: @Pekka: i am checking the session to determine who is admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the `.htaccess` or IIS configuration to deny the folder.

Comment: @pegasus: You can place one within the directory (or within any directory in your web root hierarchy).  It will govern the access of that directory and those within it, unless they have their own overriding .htaccess files.

Comment: what should i write in the .htaccess file to deny users?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways.  One way to completely lock out web users from a folder within your web root hierarchy would be to set its file system permissions to not be readable by the user context of the web server (apache user, or whatever you have set up).

Answer (score 1):

```
<Files "*">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```